# php no genera variables de formulario con domPdf

Tags: php, html, variables, dompdf

Estoy tratando de generar un archivo PDF a partir de un formulario, pero al generar el PDF no me genera los datos, me marca el siguiente error en cada linea del archivo PDF donde debería de aparecer los datos ingresados por el usuario: (Notice: Undefined variable: dep in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Form/calcular.php on line 25).
El objetivo es generar un PDF con los datos ingresados por el usuario
pero estos no se almacenan, espero puedan ayudarme y gracias de antemano.

Archivo index.html:

```
<html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
<title>Datos</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form action="calcular.php" method="POST">
        <h1>Formulario</h1>
        <div class ="dpto">
            <label for="dpto">Departamento:</label>
            <select name="dep" id="">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="Otra">Otra</option>
            <option value="Otra">Otra</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class ="campRest">
            <label for="">nombre: </label>
            <input type="text" name="nom">
            <label for="">Ciudad: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Ciudad">
            <label for="">Sobre mi: </label>
            <input type="text" name="mi">
            <label for="">Metas:</label>
            <input type="text" name="meta">
            <label for="">fecha de nacimiento: </label>
            <input type="date" name="fecha">
            <label for="">apodo: </label>
            <input type="text" name="apodo">
            <label for="">Comentarios: </label>
            <textarea cols="66" rows="5" wrap="hard" name="comentario">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Repellat laboriosam deserunt ullam tenetur error, sunt consectetur repudiandae magni. Repellat hic dolore commodi, inventore consequatur libero sapiente voluptatibus expedita illo cum.</textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Archivo calcular.php

```
    <?php
// Inicializar sesión solo si no se ha iniciado
if(!defined('SESSION_STARTED')) {
    session_start();
}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    // Si se va a procesar el formulario
    $dep = $_POST['dep'];
    $nom = $_POST['nom'];
    $Ciudad = $_POST['Ciudad'];
    $mi = $_POST['mi'];
    $meta = $_POST['meta'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $apodo = $_POST['apodo'];
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
    // Crear variable de sesión para que se pueda generar el PDF
    $_SESSION['pdf'] = [
        'dep' => $dep,
        'nom' => $nom,
        'ciudad' => $Ciudad,
        'mi' => $mi,
        'meta' => $meta,
        'fecha' => $fecha,
        'apodo' => $apodo,
        'comentario' => $comentario
    ];
    // Enlace de descarga solo si se procesa formulario
    $descarga = '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="crearPdf.php"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Descargar archivo PDF</a>';
} elseif(isset($_SESSION['pdf'])) {
    // Se va a crear el PDF
    $dep = $_SESSION['pdf']['dep'];
    $nom = $_SESSION['pdf']['nom'];
    $Ciudad = $_SESSION['pdf']['Ciudad'];
    $mi = $_SESSION['pdf']['mi'];
    $meta = $_SESSION['pdf']['meta'];
    $fecha = $_SESSION['pdf']['fecha'];
    $apodo = $_SESSION['pdf']['apodo'];
    $comentario = $_SESSION['pdf']['comentario'];
    // No hay enlace de descarga al crear PDF
    $descarga = '';
} else {
    die('No hay datos para procesar.');
}
// Salida con sintaxis HEREDOC
echo <<<HTML
<html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Datos2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<div class ="contenedor">
    <h1>Formulario</h1>
    <p><h4>Departamento</h4>$dep</p><br>
    <p><h4>nombre:</h4>$nom</p><br>
    <p><h4>Ciudad::</h4>$Ciudad</p><br>
    <p><h4>Sobre mi:</h4>$mi</p><br>
    <p><h4>Metas:</h4>$meta</p><br>
    <p><h4>fecha de nacimiento:</h4>$fecha</p><br>
    <p><h4>apodo:</h4>$apodo</p><br>
    <p><h4>Comentarios:</h4>$comentario</p><br>
</div>
$descarga
</html>
HTML; // Esta línea debe estar en la primera columna o va a generar error
```

Archivo que renderiza el PDF:

```
    <?php
// Iniciar sesión
session_start();
// Verificar que existe la variable de sesión
if(!isset($_SESSION['pdf'])) {
    die('Primero debes realizar el cálculo.');
}

// Definir constante para no duplicar inicio de sesión
define('SESSION_STARTED', 1);

// Cargamos la librería dompdf que hemos instalado en la carpeta dompdf
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// Inicializar buffer de salida
ob_start();

// Incluir script que genera HTML
include 'calcular.php';

// Obtener HTML y limpiar buffer
$html = ob_get_clean();

// Instanciamos un objeto de la clase DOMPDF.
$pdf = new DOMPDF();

// Define el tamaño y orientación del papel.
$pdf->set_paper("letter", "portrait");

// Carga el contenido HTML.
$pdf->load_html(utf8_decode($html));

// Renderiza el documento PDF.
$pdf->render();

// Enviamos el fichero PDF al navegador.
$pdf->stream('notaPdf.pdf');

// Eliminar variable de sesión
unset($_SESSION['pdf']);
```

Comment: Te está faltando el punto y coma aquí: `<p><h4>Departamento</h4><?php echo $dep?></p><br>`, prueba a ponerlo: **`<p><h4>Departamento</h4><?php echo $dep; ?></p><br>`** te recomendaría que evites lo más posible tanta mezcla de bloques HTML/PHP. Es mejor operar en entorno PHP concatenando en una variable que imprimirías al final.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en `calcular.php` siempre esperas recibir los datos por `$_POST`, sin embargo, al crear el PDF ejecutas `$html=file_get_contents("http://localhost/Formulario2/calcular.php");`  con la petición por método `$_GET` y, por supuesto, las variables no existen. Podrías crearlas como variables de sesión.

Respecto al consejo que te dieron en comentarios de no mezclar salida HTML con etiquetas de apertura y cierre de PHP, puedes usar la [sintaxis HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), donde se interpretan variables y se remplazan con el valor correspondiente.

```
<?php
// Inicializar sesión solo si no se ha iniciado
if(!defined('SESSION_STARTED') {
    session_start();
}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    // Si se va a procesar el formulario
    $dep = $_POST['dep'];
    $nom = $_POST['nom'];
    $Ciudad = $_POST['Ciudad'];
    $mi = $_POST['mi'];
    $meta = $_POST['meta'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $apodo = $_POST['apodo'];
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
    // Crear variable de sesión para que se pueda generar el PDF
    $_SESSION['pdf'] = [
        'dep' => $dep,
        'nom' => $nom,
        'ciudad' => $Ciudad,
        'mi' => $mi,
        'meta' => $meta,
        'fecha' => $fecha,
        'apodo' => $apodo,
        'comentario' => $comentario
    ];
    // Enlace de descarga solo si se procesa formulario
    $descarga = '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="crearPdf.php"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Descargar archivo PDF</a>';
} elseif(isset($_SESSION['pdf'])) {
    // Se va a crear el PDF
    $dep = $_SESSION['pdf']['dep'];
    $nom = $_SESSION['pdf']['nom'];
    $Ciudad = $_SESSION['pdf']['Ciudad'];
    $mi = $_SESSION['pdf']['mi'];
    $meta = $_SESSION['pdf']['meta'];
    $fecha = $_SESSION['pdf']['fecha'];
    $apodo = $_SESSION['pdf']['apodo'];
    $comentario = $_SESSION['pdf']['comentario'];
    // No hay enlace de descarga al crear PDF
    $descarga = '';
} else {
    die('No hay datos para procesar.');
}
// Salida con sintaxis HEREDOC
echo <<<HTML
<html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Datos2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<div class ="contenedor">
    <h1>Formulario</h1>
    <p><h4>Departamento</h4>$dep</p><br>
    <p><h4>nombre:</h4>$nom</p><br>
    <p><h4>Ciudad::</h4>$Ciudad</p><br>
    <p><h4>Sobre mi:</h4>$mi</p><br>
    <p><h4>Metas:</h4>$meta</p><br>
    <p><h4>fecha de nacimiento:</h4>$fecha</p><br>
    <p><h4>apodo:</h4>$apodo</p><br>
    <p><h4>Comentarios:</h4>$comentario</p><br>
</div>
$descarga
</html>
HTML; // Esta línea debe estar en la primera columna o va a generar error
```

En `crearPdf.php` agregas `session_start();` como primera línea y, al terminar, eliminas la variable de sesión con `unset($_SESSION['pdf']);`

En lugar de obtener el HTML con `file_get_contents()`, incluye directamente *calcular.php*, capturando el contenido con buffer de salida:

- [`ob_start()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ob-start.php): Para decirle a PHP que almacene la salida en vez de enviarla al navegador
- [`ob_get_clean()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ob-get-clean.php): Para obtener la salida, limpiar el buffer y volver al proceso normal de salida

Con esto te aseguras de que el contenido es realmente lo que deseas y evitas petición por URL que, por alguna razón, no te está devolviendo lo que esperas.

```
<?php
// Iniciar sesión
session_start();
// Verificar que existe la variable de sesión
if(!isset($_SESSION['pdf'])) {
    die('Primero debes realizar el cálculo.');
}

// Definir constante para no duplicar inicio de sesión
define('SESSION_STARTED', 1);

// Cargamos la librería dompdf que hemos instalado en la carpeta dompdf
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// Inicializar buffer de salida
ob_start();

// Incluir script que genera HTML
include 'calcular.php';

// Obtener HTML y limpiar buffer
$html = ob_get_clean();

// Instanciamos un objeto de la clase DOMPDF.
$pdf = new DOMPDF();

// Define el tamaño y orientación del papel.
$pdf->set_paper("letter", "portrait");

// Carga el contenido HTML.
$pdf->load_html(utf8_decode($html));

// Renderiza el documento PDF.
$pdf->render();

// Enviamos el fichero PDF al navegador.
$pdf->stream('notaPdf.pdf');

// Eliminar variable de sesión
unset($_SESSION['pdf']);
```

Comment: No funciono, supongo realice mal la implementación que usted menciona (soy novato jeje) pero aun así muchas gracias y mas por el tema "sintaxis HEREDOC" para seguir preparandome :D, saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué fue lo que no funcionó, hay algún error, cuál?

Comment: no me sale ningún error en pantalla, lo que pasa es que all darle clic al botón enviar, me descarga el archivo calcular.php en lugar del archivo .pdf

Comment: Revisa la actualización, ya no deberías tener problemas.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, intento añadir las capturas de pantalla pero no se como hacerlo, pero el error esta vez lo marca en el primer if del archivo calcular.php

<?php
// Inicializar sesión solo si no se ha iniciado
if(!defined('SESSION_STARTED') {
    session_start();
}

syntax error, unexpected ';' (este es el error en session_start();)

Comment: Faltaba un paréntesis: `if(!defined('SESSION_STARTED')) { session_start(); } `

Comment: sigue descargando el archivo calcular.php

Comment: Edita la pregunta para actualizar el código con el que generas el archivo PDF.

Comment: eh actualizado todo el código por cualquier cosa, saludos y gracias de antemano